# How to send request from virtual IP address to a server?

Tags: java, sockets

Can any one tell me how could i send request to a server using different IP address. Let me explain the requirement; I have to create n no of different virtual IP address in my machine, and then I have to sent request to a different server using those individual virtual IP address. Like one request from one virtual IP address , one from another virtual IP address. Can anyone tell me how could I achieve this programatically ? I am developing my code in java so if you have any code or concept on this please share with me.

Answer (score 4):

It's done the same way in Java as any other language: you bind the socket to the address you want to connect from, before you connect.

```
Socket s = new Socket();
/*
 * Change the 192.168.0.1 to whatever IP address you want the connection
 * to come from. If your IP address is stored in an InetAddress object,
 * you can use that too, instead of a string.
 */
SocketAddress from = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.1", 0);
SocketAddress to = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.2", 80);
s.bind(from);
s.connect(to);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what are the configuration change is required in my IP settings? I am using Windows XP

Comment: @Abhisek: I don't know anything about Windows XP. On Linux, you can add IP aliases for all the addresses you want to use.

Comment: @Abhisek, this may not work for you in Windows XP, but here is a link to how to create multiple virtual IP addresses in Windows versions that have PowerShell http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/94927-how-to-create-multiple-hundreds-ip-address-using-powershell-in-server-2003